# Сборка под WinCE в VS2008

Tags: visual-studio, сборка, windows-ce

Здравствуйте.

В связи с приобретением устройства под управлением WinCE 6 захотелось попробовать написать для него программу. Возникла неожиданная проблема: не получается собрать проект для платформы WinCE.

Сейчас порядок действий у меня такой: в VS2008 создаю проект "Visual C#"->"Смарт-устройство". В свойствах проекта конечная платформа Any CPU, "Проект"->"Сменить конечную платформу"->"Windows CE".

Проект простенький в стиле HelloWorld. В VS под эмулятором запускается без проблем. Но когда я делаю релиз, то получается приложение win32, которое без проблем запускается в Win7, но не в эмуляторе WinCE не на самом устройстве не работает.

Прошу помощи в решении этого вопроса, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ну для начала надо установить Net.Framework на сам аппарат т.к поумолчанию шарп в винмобилах не установлен или там валяется какая-нибудь старая дряхлая версия... и возможно надо сам проект создавать ( на этапе новый проект ) как win 32 mobile ( точно в с++ оболчке на счет с# врать не стану ). на моей памяти не было проблем с запуском c# приложений собранный на VS 2008 для мобилы asus p750 c 6.1 оригинальной виндой. где-то на просторах [статей](http://dimonvideo.ru/) есть моя древняя публикация как запустить C++/Qt4 приготовленном в vs2008 для винмобилки.

Comment: Что то  так и не разобрался. Проблема в том, что получаемый exe файл не запускается даже в эмуляторе, зато прекрасно запускается как обычное приложение на win7. В то же время, если запускать проект в VS, то открывается собственный эмулятор VS и в нем все прекрасно работает. Exe файл после сборки я беру из папки Release внутри папки проекта. Есть ли в моих действиях ошибка?